# IE7 button not styling properly, error in CSS styling?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, testing, internet-explorer-7

Hello i'm testing my site in IE7 and where the orange link box sits for **create account** is not displaying properly, the bottom of the orange rectangle is cut off. Is there a CSS fix for this? If you have IE9 you can view this in F12 > compatibility mode set to IE7 and look at the orange buttons.

the rule styling the a element is here:

Ideally I need a CSS solution and the reason it is going wrong -

```
#home-content a {

  padding:6px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #DA7700;
  height:40px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: This may or may not help you, but we stopped supporting IE7 when Microsoft dropped support for it. Depending on the amount of traffic you get from users still using this highly outdated browser, you may want to instead consider urging them to update to a modern browser. Again, this assumes there isn't a valid case in your business for maintaining support for IE7. Good luck!

Comment: it's a technical report for study, must account for older browsers. Do you have any references from MS stating that they dropped IE7?

Comment: It is hard to find official information, but here is an article from January 2010 where [Microsoft warns users to upgrade to IE8 and stop using IE6 and IE7 immediately due to security vulnerabilities](http://apcmag.com/microsoft-warns-stop-using-ie6-ie7-now.htm).

Answer (score 6):

For left button: "create account":
Add two more att:

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

Delete this one:

```
height:40px;
```

I think this should solve your problem.
Same is for the right button  (only padding without height, aligned center and displayed as block)